# problem in updating the resources folder of an already deployed cf app

Tags: java, cloud

1. I have a requirement where I need to create/update files in the resources folder of an application which is already deployed in cloud foundry.
2. Once it's updated I am trying to fetch all the files present in the resources folder through a rest endpoint which returns me a zip of all the files present in the resources folder.
3. When I do a get on this endpoint, I am not finding the files which were added/updated in step 1 are not present in the zip file.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Try to be more concrete, like adding concrete file names, code being used, etc.